# VBA populate target cells getting data and reference from other sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, export-to-excel

I'm trying to copy a range from a looped iteration (The Range "M2:U11" changes based on the values of cell "A6") and paste them into a separate sheet in a well-arranged manner.

So I have a new sheet (let's name it PDF Template). I want to paste the relevant Ranges(Tables) and format/distribute them exactly as it is shown in this imagee>>>>:

[well-arranged ranges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKUxj.png)

I don't know if it would be possible. Any answers?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please include the VBA you are working with and the specific place you are stuck.

Comment: Okay. At first, I thought of copying and pasting it to PowerPoint and after scouring the internet I created a workable code for that. Here it is>>>

Answer (score 0):

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

```
'Declare our Variables
Dim rR As Range, rA6 As Range
Dim powerpointapp As Object
Dim mypresentation As Object
Dim myslide As Object
Dim myshape As Object
Dim i As Integer


'assigning range into variable
Set rR = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("M1:U11")
Set rA6 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A6")     '<<< Is A6 also on this sheet? Else correct sheet name

'If we have already opened powerpoint
Set powerpointapp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
                  
'If powerpoint is not opened
If powerpointapp Is Nothing Then Set powerpointapp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

'To create a new presentation
Set mypresentation = powerpointapp.Presentations.Add

 
'Loop through all the values in "A6"
         'If Range("A6") = loop 1 To 100 Then Range("M1:U11").Select
         'Copy the Selection
         'Paste each iteration on a new slide on Powerpoint
         
For i = 1 To 300    'Loop A6 through all values from 1 to 300
    rA6 = i

    Set myslide = mypresentation.slides.Add(1, 11)
    'Copy the puzzle
    rR.Copy
    
    'to paste range
    myslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2
    Set myshape = myslide.Shapes(myslide.Shapes.Count)
    myshape.Left = 250
    myshape.Top = 150
    
Next i
    
powerpointapp.Visible = True
powerpointapp.Activate

'to clear the cutcopymode from clipboard
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

End Sub

Comment: It works fine but the problem is, I wanted each range to be arranged four to a page. I tried to get answers for that but no one got it right. So I decided to try this method. Copy the range and paste its values on a different sheet then print it as a PDF. So far I've got nothing as far as VBA is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

If you always have 4 sheets, you can just copy the range from each sheet, tell it where to paste it on the PDF sheet. Then copy the range on the PDF sheet that has all four of the sheets boxes before pasting it into your spreadsheet.